# SSIS package failing as part of a job

Tags: sql-server, types, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

I have an SSIS package that imports data from an oracle data source to a native SQLtable. I've run it several times and it works fine.

Oddly, when I try to run it as part of a job, it returns a bunch of

> Column xx  cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

The destination columns are mostly `Varchar`, the source are mostly `varchar2`. I figure that I can convert the destination to `Nvarchar`, but I don't really understand why the package would run outside of the job but not within it.

Edit: I tried changing all the tables to `Nvarchar` and it did not remedy the problem.

Comment: What are the source and destination? Is there any parameters/variable that affect the data flow?

Comment: @Hadi I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for. It's just a package configured in SLQ Management studio, the output query xml looks like `<outputColumn id="23" name="TRANS_CODE" description="" lineageId="23" precision="0" scale="0" length="2" dataType="str" codePage="1252" sortKeyPosition="0" comparisonFlags="0" specialFlags="0" errorOrTruncationOperation="Conversion" errorRowDisposition="FailComponent" truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" externalMetadataColumnId="22" mappedColumnId="0"/>
` for each column if that helps.

Comment: is the connection manager in the configuration same as the one you run in local?